How can I use arguments containing ";" to subprocess.run?
I need to launch a JVM from a Python script. For this I'm trying to use subprocess.run. One of the arguments to the JVM is the classpath. In Windows the separator in a Java classpath is the semicolon ;. I need to add several JARs to the classpath.
This works perfectly fine when I manually launch the JVM from the command line. But when I try to launch it with subprocess.run it seems like the part of the classpath which is after the semicolon is ignored. I suspect this has something to do with the fact that the semicolon is the Windows command separator. Anyone knows how to get around it?
Failing code
def run_groovy_script(groovy_script: str, *args):
    # This function calls sys.exit in case of error. The idea is to run several commands in sequence and immediately abort with error message if one fails.
    # Construct the command to run the Groovy script with arguments
    command = ["groovy.bat", "-cp", "tools/slf4j-simple-2.0.13.jar;tools", groovy_script] + list(args)

    try:    
        result = subprocess.run(command, check=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"{groovy_script} failed with return code {e.returncode}")
        sys.exit(1)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred executing {groovy_script}: {str(e)}")
        sys.exit(1)

Successful cmd invocation
groovy.bat -cp "tools/slf4j-simple-2.0.13.jar;tools" tools/script.groovy build hej


It would be easier for us to fix your problem if you show us your code.

Show us your approach and contrast that with approaches such as How to invoke a java program with classpath from Python 3.x

[edit] the question to add a [mre].


launch a JVM from a Python script [with] subprocess.run()

You declined to tell us how you're calling .run(),
both in the original question and upon being repeatedly
prompted by the community.
It appears you want to play the SO Guessing Game.
Fine, I will spin the wheel of fortune and take my chances.
I assert that you invoked it as .run( ..., shell=True).
Don't do that.
Prefer to .split() that command string so you have a list of str.
Carefully adjust it so each element is a distinct argv argument,
for example in ['java', ...] the initial element launches the JVM.
If you had offered an
MRE
I would know what the subsequent elements should be.
Calling .run() with a list of strings and the default shell=False
gets around the shell command parsing issue reported in your question.


need to launch a JVM from a Python script

Well, you're clearly not asking python to launch a JVM.
Rather, python is executing some hidden batch file that
needs its arguments carefully crafted to match its spec,
which you've not yet successfully done.
And then the .bat file fires up one or more JVMs.
You subsequently revealed that you executed
    command = ["groovy.bat", "-cp", "tools/slf4j-simple-2.0.13.jar;tools", groovy_script] + list(args)

This is quite different from
C:\> groovy.bat -cp "tools/slf4j-simple-2.0.13.jar;tools" tools/script.groovy build hej

You have a shell command parsing issue, it's just
not at the python .run() level.
It's produced when cmd.exe interprets the .bat file.
You intended to execute this:
    command = ["groovy.bat", "-cp", '"tools/slf4j-simple-2.0.13.jar;tools"', groovy_script] + list(args)


To better understand tricky details of python quoting,
try running these commands:
print("ab 'cd ef' gh")
print('ij "kl mn" op')


I was given less than an hour of not responding before you stated "You declined". I would say that's a bit hasty.
You assert btw is wrong. I do call run with a list of strings and shell=False.
